# Intersection of nontrivial normal subgroups of a solvable group

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that a finite group G is solvable and not cyclic.  Is the intersection of all nontrivial normal subgroups of G necessarily trivial?

Serre seems to suggest that this, or something similar, is true, on p. 94 of *Local Fields*.

EDIT: Serre does NOT imply this.  The Hasse-Arf Theorem only applies to abelian extensions, where the above is true.  Thanks again for the replies.

Comment: Where *exactly* in that page Serre seems to imply such a thing?

Comment: In his argument that Prop. 11 will imply the Hasse-Arf Theorem.  He claims that since the (solvable) group G/G'' contains a nontrivial subgroup G'/G'', there must exist a cyclic quotient H of G/G'', such that the image of G' in H is nontrivial.

Comment: Yes, but if all nontrivial normal subgroups of G/G'' contained G'/G'', then wouldn't it be impossible to construct such a thing?

Comment: My earlier comment was silly (I removed it). I think (looking at Serre) he is asserting that $G/G''$ is itself a product of cyclic groups.

Comment: That is what he says, but it seems to me that he can't be sure that G/G'' will be abelian.

Comment: Perhaps there is much more to read *before* to understand, but for the fact that $\;G''\;$ is *not* the second commutator group  but a ramification one, I can't see there why $\;G/G''\;$ is solvable and where does the intersection thing kicks in...

Comment: The non-trivial semidirect product of two cyclic groups isn't abelian, but it's the product of two cyclic groups...

Comment: G/G'' is solvable because G is solvable (see p. 68).  Also see that page to see why G/G'' could equal G and not necessarily be abelian. (Thanks for your help, BTW, and sorry if I opened a can of worms.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't true -- consider $S_3$; it has one nontrivial normal subgroup, $A_3$.

Comment: Thanks for the counter-example.  Especially concerning is that this is the semi-direct product of a (normal) p-group with a cyclic group prime to p, meaning it could (potentially) be the Galois group of a totally ramified extension of Q_3.